# Creating a function to implement full outer joins in Sybase

Tags: user-defined-functions, sap-ase, outer-join

I have a long nested full outer join sequence I need to implement in Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise. Is it possible to write a function for this?

I want to simplify the code below:

```
select t1.col_01, t1.col_02, TOT_Jan, TOT_Feb 
from  
  (select a.col_01, a.col_02, sum(b.col_XX) as TOT_Jan 
   FROM vw_aux a ...
    and year(b.tms_mydate) = 2012 
    and month(b.tms_mydate) = 1 
   ... ) t1 
left outer join 
  (select a.col_01, a.col_02, sum(b.col_XX) as TOT_Feb 
    ... and year(b.tms_mydate) = 2012 
    and month(b.tms_mydate) = 2 
   ... ) t2 on t1.col_aux = t2.col_aux 
UNION 
(select a.col_01, a.col_02, sum(b.col_XX) as TOT_Jan ...) t1 
right outer join (select a.col_01, a.col_02, sum(b.col_XX) as TOT_Feb ...) t2 
on ...
```

Creating a function like this:

```
funcion myfullouterjoin (vw_aux, table_01, col_aux, col_01, col_02, tms_mydate, TOT_Jan, TOT_Feb)
```

Comment: Why not create a view?

Comment: I am trying to avoid a kind of Spaghetti code here.
The function would make the code more readable.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you Provide an example?

Comment: Don't do it in the comments, edit your question and add this information there please.

Comment: Thanks OfirW. Deleting the code in the comments right now.

Answer (score 0):

Functions do not have output parameters, therefore, you cannot implement your query there.
However, it seems to me that a Stored Procedure or View perfectly fit your needs.

You can check Sybase documentation: [Functions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1502/html/commands/CHDEDGJI.htm), [Stored Procedures](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1502/html/commands/X52197.htm).

Comment: Thanks OfirW. I'll try to write one.